# dual map structure implementation?

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, std

I'm looking for a standard dual-map structure - is there one implemented in std/boost/another standard C++ library?

When I say "dual-map" I mean a map which can be indexed efficiently both by the key and the "value" (it actually has two key types instead of one key type and one value type).

for example:

```
dualmap<int,string> m;
m[1] = "foo";
m["bar"] = 2
int a = m["bar"]; // a = 2
```

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's [boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) if you don't want all the horsepower of boost multi index.

Answer (score 5):

Boost multi-index is probably what you want - see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html