# How to make a std::unordered_map but with two keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a list of items and each item has a UID and an index in the list. Depending on the situation I can only access the item via the UID or the index of the item, never both. To store these items I need a data type that can have two keys and behaves like `std::unordered_map`. Something like this: `std::multi_unordered_map<int, int, ItemType> items;`, where both `int`s are keys. The important thing is I should only need one of the two keys to access the item.

I have seen a few versions of "maps with multiple keys" but none fit my usecase.

- [Tessil's library](https://github.com/Tessil/ordered-map) is great, but it only maintains order of insertion (which would be fine as it is always going to be equal to the index of the element) and does not allow to access elements using it.
- [This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-two-keys-with-a-stdmap) answer has a nice solution, but it required knowledge of both keys simultaneously, which I will not have. [This GeeksForGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-multidimensional-map-in-c/) has the same issue

Is there a library or accepted (standard) solution for this issue?

The only solution I can think of is something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> a; //UID, intermediate_value
std::unordered_map<int, int> b; //index, intermediate_value
std::unordered_map<int, ItemType> items; //intermediate_value, item
```

Then, I can access the intermediate value using the relevant structure and then use the intermediate value to find the item. Of course I am sure I can make this much more efficient using a `std::vector` instead of `std::unordered_map`, but regardless that is a lot of extra steps, which I would like to avoid.

Additionally, I am looking for small libraries (like [Tessil's](https://github.com/Tessil/ordered-map) I mentioned before). I prefer to avoid something like boost.

Comment: There's no built-in solution. I'd create two `unordered_map`s, one mapping key1->`ItemType`, and the second mapping key2->iterator_into_first_map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A cross between std::multimap and std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938389) Or maybe [dual map structure implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2408181)

Comment: @JaMiT While the `boost::multi_index` seems to do what I want I am trying to avoid a library as heavy as boost. As for the second one, the dual map will not work as I need two keys and a value, not just two keys. The answer to that question also involves boost. I will update the question to reflect this preference.

Comment: You can make a struct containing the data of the two keys and a compare operator on it.

Comment: Multi index and bimap are both header only, you could probably extract them from boost and use them independently

Comment: @AlanBirtles That is good to know. Although for now I like Jerry Coffin's solution for its cleanliness and lack of adding another library at all.

Comment: @Eshy *"I am trying to avoid a library as heavy as boost."* -- Aside from 20 of the 160+ modules, Boost is only as heavy as you need. Most of the libraries are header-only and heavily templated, which means only the parts you use get compiled. The ones that are not header-only do not need to be linked in unless you use them, so you're still pretty close to no library overhead. *Of course, if you still want to avoid Boost, that's your call.*

Comment: @Eshy *"the dual map will not work as I need two keys and a value, not just two keys"* -- That's a reason I said "maybe" for that one. Still, it's only a blocker if the values need to change. If the values never change, you could combine one key and the value into a single `struct`, use that as the second bimap key, but define the bimap's second comparison to compare only the "real" key (ignore the value part of the `struct`). *Just providing options, not saying you should. The question suggested to me that the values do not need to change, but I admit that is an unwarranted leap in logic.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably store the items themselves in a vector, then create an `unordered_map` from the UID to the index into the vector, something like this:

```cpp
template <class UID, class Item>
class DualMap {
    std::unordered_map<UID, std::size_t> m;
    std::vector<Item> items;
public:
    // insert an item, return its index:
    std::size_t insert(UID id, Item item) { 
        items.push_back(item);
        m.insert(id, items.size()-1);
        return items.size()-1;
    }

    Item *find_by_id(UID id) {
       auto pos = m.find(id);
       if (pos == m.end())
           return nullptr;
       return &items[pos->second];
    }

    Item *find_by_index(std::size_t index) {
        return items[index];
    }
};
```

This isn't *drastically* different from the approach you outline in the question, but still strikes me as rather cleaner and simpler.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!!! Although pretty much just an abstraction to my napkin-solution, it has the benefit of easily being reused and despite some overhead is very similar to just having two `int`s and a `ItemType`.

Comment: @Eshy: Fair warning: I did a little bit more editing to correct a couple of typos and such.

Comment: No worries! I have a rule to never copy-paste code (with exceptions, of course) so I caught the edits. It allows to me to learn it fully. Thanks again!

Comment: @JerryCoffin why did you reopen this question rather than posting your answer on  the duplicate?

Comment: Removal of item would require to "complexify" the code though (maybe just to store `std::optional<Item>`)...

Comment: @AlanBirtles: because at least as I read it, the duplicate isn't really a duplicate.

Comment: @Jarod42: To support deletion, you'd have to start with a clear definition of what deletion means, and what the index means. In something like a vector, all indices 0..Size()-1 are always valid. But with this, either that wouldn't be true, or else the relationship between an ID and an index could change without warning. I think we'd need more info from the OP to choose between those meaningfully.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a variant can serve as your key, since you never have both UID and index

```cpp
struct UID {
  int value;
};

struct Index {
  int value;
};

std::unordered_map<std::variant<UID, Index>, ItemType> items;
```

---

**Update**

This is a incomplete proposal. See the accept one.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to access using UID or index as the program requires. I cannot predetermine which I will be using as I will have to use either depending on the program's need at any given time. A `std::variant` will only allow one or the other.

Comment: @Eshy, I might misunderstood the problem. I think we can do `std::unordered_map<std::variant<UID, Index>, ItemType*> items`, and store the `items` in a separate vector. When inserting items, register both UID and Index with the pointer to the item's storage

Comment: To clarify, I need to store a value that can be accessed by either one of two keys, a uid or an index. It must be stored along side both of them. Not just one at a time, as either can be used at any given time.

Comment: Sorry, I answered before your edit loaded. This is a valid solution, but it is equivalent to my suggestion (although more optimized). It is also very similar to @HolyBlackCat's comment. I do appreciate it, however.

Comment: @Eshy, Never mind. I am always looking forward to seeing better solutions.